# Javascript error when using Messenger Connect client-side library in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, sitefinity, liveid

I'm having a problem implementing the new Messenger Connect functionality inside an existing Sitefinity site to enable client logins using Live IDs.

Namely, when I'm using the following code to implement the client-side functionality:

```
<head runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.live.net/4.1/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form runat="server" id="form1">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
    <wl:app
        client-id="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wl_wrap_client_id"] %>"
        scope="WL_Profiles.View"
        callback-url="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wl_wrap_client_callback"] %>?wl_session_id=<%=SessionId %>"
        channel-url="/channel.htm">
    </wl:app>
```

... I get three errors in Firebug that I can't quite identify correctly:

> Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be
>   converted to type 'Sys.IDisposable'.
>   Parameter name: object

(in ScriptResource.axd?d=.... line 4993)

> Sys.Application._doInitialize is not a
>   function

(in MicrosoftAjaxBase.js line 1)

> Sys.InvalidOperationException: The
>   script 'MicrosoftAjaxGlobalization.js'
>   has been referenced multiple times. If
>   referencing Microsoft AJAX scripts
>   explicitly, set the MicrosoftAjaxMode
>   property of the ScriptManager to
>   Explicit.

(in ScriptResource.axd?d=.... line 984)

The errors are only triggered when I include the `loader.js` script from js.live.net.

*EDIT*: Seems the errors aren't necessarily triggered in that order. Refreshing the page seems to shuffle those errors and/or introduce other ones, such as a `Sys.ParameterCountException` in `ScriptResource.axd?...` on line 1842, for example.

Comment: I've had this error as well and haven't had any luck finding a solution yet. It seems that Messenger Connect uses its own version of the AJAX loader functionality and doesn't play nice with the existing version if you use it for other things (like async loading everything else).

Comment: See if this helps as well regardless of the originating culprit to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103128/javascript-runtime-error-for-microsoft-ajax-scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, I tried some combinations here, and the one that worked was:

1) Set the ScriptMode property of the ScriptManager to **Release**;

2) Load the MSN library in the CodeBehind Page_Load event, using the ClientScript class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "live", "http://js.live.net/4.0/loader.js");
}
```

Firebug isn't showing any error anymore, and in my case, the authentication window is opening as desired.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

As told before, here follows the whole code I use to avoid this issue:

*Default.aspx*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wl="http://apis.live.net/js/2010">
<head>
    <title>SignIn Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function appLoaded(appLoadedEventArgs) {
        }
        function signInCallback(signInCompletedEventArgs) {
            if (signInCompletedEventArgs.get_resultCode() === Microsoft.Live.AsyncResultCode.success)
            {
                alert('Sign-in successful.');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Sign-in failed.');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="form1">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <wl:app channel-url="http://labs.asteria.com.br/wlm/Channel.html" 
        callback-url="http://labs.asteria.com.br/wlm/Callback.aspx?wl_session_id=<%= Session.SessionID %>"
        client-id="0000000044052209" 
        scope="WL_Profiles.View" 
        onload="{{appLoaded}}">
    </wl:app>
    <wl:signin 
        id="signInControl" 
        signedintext="Signed in. Click to sign out." 
        signedouttext="Click to sign in."
        onsignin="{{signInCallback}}" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Default.aspx.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "live", "http://js.live.net/4.0/loader.js");
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="wl_wrap_client_secret" value="[YOUR SECRET KEY]"/>
    <add key="wl_wrap_client_id" value="0000000044052209"/>
    <add key="wl_wrap_client_callback" value="http://labs.asteria.com.br/wlm/Callback.aspx"/>
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

To see it running, you can access http://labs.asteria.com.br/wlm. It seems that the Consent URL (https://consent.live.com/AccessToken.aspx) is not responding at this time.

Comment: I'm not currently working on any project involving this so if anyone can verify this answer, I'll gladly mark it as answered.

Comment: Awarding the bounty as best answer even if unconfirmed. Would be nice to see all the code if not too long.

Comment: For sure, I'll publish it later, together with a working sample.

Comment: Marking it as answered, since I can't confirm the answer. @Tuco & @Mark Schultheiss, comment if anything breaks.