# JavaScript runtime error for Microsoft AJAX scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET web forms project in VS.NET 2012 that has been running *great* for weeks. All of the sudden out of nowhere I'm getting the following everytime I begin to debug the project:

> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 12302 in
>   http:// localhost :1449/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=_Onj24X0Yu7cK2nh78YBmVwMlQTGcakS5HZSOI_a6SM1
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
>   The script 'Timer.js' has been referenced multiple times. If
>   referencing Microsoft AJAX scripts explicitly, set the
>   MicrosoftAjaxMode property of the ScriptManager to Explicit.

(note: added spaces in error message to word 'localhost' because these URLs are not formed well for posting; link is irrelevant anyway)

This is odd because it just began to occur out of nowhere. I did some searching on this and came up with anything that would make it work.

In the auto-generated `BundleConfig.cs`, this file is only listed 1x:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
          "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

    // Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
}
```

In the web.config there is no duplicate or listing otherwise for the timer. I did a search on the project and this was the only place it was listed.

I also made sure all of the `NuGet` packages where up to date. Anyone understand or know what has caused this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. I have got to believe one of the NuGet package updates I downloaded was registering these files *separately*, and at the same time must have been new logic. I say this because this issue started out of nowhere.

The solution was simply to comment out or remove the offending scripts that were being registered more than 1x in the `BundleConfig.cs` file. Here is the modified section of script registration:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
         "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
         "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js"));
```

The following (2) scripts were the culprit:

```
"~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
"~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"
```

After removing them the error went away, the functionality within those scripts *still* works (I use Ajax timers), and the error went away.